# Найти в строке 16 цифр и извлечь их

Tags: php

Есть строка с текстом, среди этого текста есть цифры, которые следуют друг за другом.

Строка может быть таких вариантов:

```
текст текст 1234 5678 1234 5678 текст 
текст текст 1234567887654321 текст
текст текст 1234-5678-1234-5678 текст
```

Как извлечь только эти цифры, без лишних символов (без пробелов и тд.)?

Извлечь просто цифры из строки не вариант, так как там могут быть ненужные, например `текст 25 текст 1234 5678 1234 5678 текст`.

То есть нужно чтобы извлекало только 16 цифр, которые следуют друг за другом.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Подберите полный список допустимых разделителей внутри нужной группы (пробел, тире, ...). Удалите их одним регэкспом (в более сложном случае - из фрагмента *цифра-разделители-цифра* оставить только обрамляющие цифры). Затем вторым регэкспом извлеките группу из 16 цифровых символов подряд. Всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть как вариант ([см. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/U4BgFa/1)):

```
$content = '
    текст текс 1234-5678-1234-5678 текст
    текст текст 1234 5678 1234 5678 текст
';

preg_match_all('/(?:[-\h]*\d){16}/', $content, $matches);

$matches = array_map(function($x) {
    return preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $x);
}, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: то что нужно! Благодарю. А не подскажете еще как заменить найденные числа на 0 ?

Comment: @Денис, все 16 цифр заменить на 0?

Comment: да, 0 это я для примера, там буду слова свои подставлять, вместо найденных цифр

Comment: @Денис, тут все проще, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71008ed99f9786ac9dce64cf0d83731632a64c13

Comment: @Let'ssayPie `$word = '|вместо 16-ти цифр|';` 

`echo preg_replace('~\b(?:[-\h]*\d){16}~', $word, $content);`

Comment: @Эдуард, да-да, можно так, что-то я решил все усложнить :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = 'текст 1234 5678 text  1234 5678 текст';
$str2 = 'текст 25 текст 1234 5678 1234 5678 текст';

$delete_regex = '~[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]~ui';

$str1_filtered = preg_replace($delete_regex, '', $str1);
$str2_filtered = preg_replace($delete_regex, '', $str2);

$str1_filtered_finaly = [];
preg_match('~([0-9]{16,})~', $str1_filtered, $str1_filtered_finaly);

$str2_filtered_finaly = [];
preg_match('~([0-9]{16,})~', $str2_filtered, $str2_filtered_finaly);

print_r(isset($str1_filtered_finaly[1]) ? $str1_filtered_finaly[1] : 'No match');
print_r(isset($str2_filtered_finaly[1]) ? $str2_filtered_finaly[1] : 'No match');
```

Comment: Выражение `~([0-9]{16,})~` выполнит захват от 16 и более цифр, в условиях написано что только 16.

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал условие -_-)